# Connecting a Switch to a Relay

Tags: switches, relay

I am trying to connect 2 motor boats with a relay to a switch. I received a drawing, but I am not understanding how the wires connect into the illuminated switch.

Here is the switch and the drawing.

[image: photo]

[image: drawing]

Can you help me with this ?

Comment: This kind of drawing is essentially useless, because it doesn't identify any of the individual terminals on the individual items. Also, a photograph of the back of the switch is useless without a part number and/or a datasheet to go with it. Can you provide a proper schematic diagram and links to data about all of the components involved? Otherwise, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Could you post a link to the datasheet of the switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted, I don't read German, and it took a bit of guess work, but considering they are standardish parts, this should be correct. Your switch is not the same kind of illuminated switch used in the circuit you show. But it can be wired the same.

Battery positive to the C (Common) pin. Connect the + on the switch to the NO pin. Connect the relay pin 85 to the NO pin as well. The battery negative should go to the Relay Pin 86 AND the switch pin -.

The rest of the circuit is as normally connected (Battery Positive to the Switch's C pin and the Relay pin 30, etc etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRJdPY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Finally i received an image of the switch wired. Its the same you explained but the + connected to the NO pin.

Comment: @DanielMarques Sorry, you are right, NO pin.